# page-id/notifications returns an empty array

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, desktop-application

I'm writing a desktop application using Facebook SDK .NET. This app must do somethink for every post, comment or message sent to a Facebook page. I'm using the page-id/notifications API command:

page-id/notifications?fields=id,title,unread,application,from,message,object&limit=250

This command returns correct unseen count in summary section but data array is empty:

```
{
  "data": [
  ],
  "summary": {
    "unseen_count": 2,
    "updated_time": "2016-02-05T14:53:10+0000"
  }
}
```

If someone write a new wall post on the page or send a private message to the page, unseen_count is updated but data array is always empty. If someoune write a comment to an exisiting wall post unseen_count is updates and data array is populated with a comment notification (only this type of notification are added to data array):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "notif_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "title": "yyyyy yyyyyyy commented on his post.",
      "unread": 1,
      "application": {
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/games/?app_id=xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "name": "Feed Comments",
        "id": "1967xxxxxxx"
      },
      "from": {
        "name": "Mxxxx Sxxxxxx",
        "id": "1020xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      },
      "object": {
        "created_time": "2016-02-05T14:52:32+0000",
        "message": "ABCDEFGHILMNOPQRSTUVZ",
        "id": "36xxxxxxxxxxxx0_546xxxxxxxxxxx0"
      },
      "to": {
        "name": "Ixxxxxxx",
        "id": "36xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "previous": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "next": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  },
  "summary": {
    "unseen_count": 3,
    "updated_time": "2016-02-05T14:55:23+0000"
  }
}
```

Is it an API bug or there is something wrong in my API request?
I CANNOT use real time notification.

Thanks
Marco

Comment: If it is not working as expected, file a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Have you found a solution?